# 3D object recognition: Deep Learning VS Descriptors

Tags: comparison, deep-learning, descriptor, object-recognition

- Is the arrival of Deep Learning methodes [(Pang, Neumann. 2016)](http://graphics.usc.edu/cgit/people/gpang/files/papers/icpr2016_final.pdf) [(Su, Maji. 2016)](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/mvcnn/docs/su15mvcnn.pdf) the end of Descriptors methodes (FPFH, SHOT, Spin Image, ...)?
- Can we consider Descriptor as obsolets techniques? or is there a case where they are the only or the better solution?